# asp.net core mvc when add or remove partial view from controller

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I made a form with partial view so when the user click on the button add dependent it will redirect to the action

```
public IActionResult AddNewDependents(NewMedicalCardDto newMedicalCardDto, int id)
    {
        
        for (int i = 0; i < id+1; i++) 
        {
        newMedicalCardDto.DependentsDto.Add(new DependentDto {Id=i, DependentName = "", RelationToApplicant = 0, DependentDateOfBirth = DateTime.Now, DependentNationalId = "", DependentMobileNumber = "" });
        }
        return PartialView("_Dependent", newMedicalCardDto);
            
    }
```

It's working but the problem when i fill the data for the first dependent and i click to add another dependent all the information in first dependent is deleted .
the other problem with the delete button if add two dependent for example and i want to delete one dependent the action i made will delete all of the dependent

```
 public IActionResult RemoveNewDependent(NewMedicalCardDto newMedicalCardDto, int id)
    {
        var remove = newMedicalCardDto.DependentsDto.Find(x => x.Id == id);
        newMedicalCardDto.DependentsDto.Remove(remove);
         


        return PartialView("_Dependent", newMedicalCardDto);
    }
```

And this is my jquery to call the Action AddNewDependents

```
        $("#AddNewDependent").click(function (evt) {
        debugger;
        //var fileupload = $("#NationalImage").get(0);
        //var files = fileupload.files;
        var data = new FormData();
        /**/
        data.append('id', $('#ItemCount').val());
        // You can update the jquery selector to use a css class if you want
        //$("input[type='text'").each(function (x, y) {
            //    data.append($(y).attr("name"), $(y).val());
            //});

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/AddDependent/AddNewDependents",
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                data: data,
                success: function (message) {
                    $('#AddNewDiv').html(message);
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("there was error !");
                }
            });
    });
```

Comment: Hi @Abdulmajeed,  I want to confirm the following with you: 1, Where is the AddNewDependent and RemoveDependent button, in the partial view or main page? 2. In the AddNewDependent JavaScript event, you just post the ItemCount to the action method, so the newMedicalCardDto is null. 3. You are according to the count value to add Dependents for the newMedicalCardDto, in remove method, you are also removing the Dependent from the newMedicalCardDto. So, you want to add or remove Dependents for one newMedicalCardDto instance, right?

Comment: 1- the AddNewDependent in the main page and RemoveDependent button in the partial view 2- you are right maybe thats why when i'm adding another dependent all the other data from dependent is deleted 3- i want to delete the dependent i'm sending with id not all the other dependent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [Session](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-5.0#session-state) to store the user data (the newMedicalCardDto).

Note: Session state uses a store maintained by the app to persist data across requests from a client. Critical application data should be stored in the user database.

According to your code and description, I create a sample with the following code, you could refer it.

1. Refer the [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-5.0#session-state) to configure session and add session extensions (the SessionExtensions is used to store objct in the session).
2. Create the following model:

   ```
    public class DependentDto
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string DependentName { get; set; }
        public int RelationToApplicant { get; set; }
        public DateTime DependentDateOfBirth { get; set; }
        public string DependentNationalId { get; set; }
        public string DependentMobileNumber { get; set; }
    }
    public class NewMedicalCardDto 
    {
        public int ItemCount { get; set; }
        public List<DependentDto> DependentsDto { get; set; }
    }
   ```
3. Create a _Dependent.cshtml partial view: used to display the dependents.

   ```
    @model MVCWebApplication.Models.NewMedicalCardDto

    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th> Id </th>
                <th> DependentName </th>
                <th> RelationToApplicant </th>
                <th>  DependentDateOfBirth </th>
                <th> DependentNationalId </th>
                <th>  DependentMobileNumber </th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @if (Model.DependentsDto!= null && Model.DependentsDto.Count > 0)
            { 
                @foreach (var item in Model.DependentsDto)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Id)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DependentName)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.RelationToApplicant)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DependentDateOfBirth)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DependentNationalId)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DependentMobileNumber)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="button" value="Delete" id="DeleteDependent" data-ItemId="@item.Id" class="btn btn-primary DeleteDependent" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            }
                else
                {
                <tr><td colspan="7"><span>empty</span>
                    </td></tr>

                }
        </tbody>
    </table>
   ```
4. Create _AddDependent.cshtml partial view: it is used to add one Dependent to the newMedicalCardDto.DependentsDto.

   ```
    @model MVCWebApplication.Models.DependentDto


    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-4">
                <label asp-for="Id" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Id" class="form-control" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-4">
                <label asp-for="DependentName" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="DependentName" class="form-control" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-4">
                <label asp-for="RelationToApplicant" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="RelationToApplicant" class="form-control" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-4">
                <label asp-for="DependentDateOfBirth" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="DependentDateOfBirth" class="form-control" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-4">
                <label asp-for="DependentNationalId" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="DependentNationalId" class="form-control" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-4">
                <label asp-for="DependentMobileNumber" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="DependentMobileNumber" class="form-control" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row"> 
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="AddDependent" value="AddDependent" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
   ```
5. In the main page(index.cshtml):

   ```
    @model MVCWebApplication.Models.NewMedicalCardDto

    @{
        ViewData["Title"] = "DependentIndex";
        Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    }

    <h1>DependentIndex</h1>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <form asp-action="DependentIndex">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="ItemCount" class="control-label"></label>
                    <input asp-for="ItemCount" class="form-control" />
                    <input id="AddNewDependent" value="AddNewDependent" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" />
                </div>
                <div class="container" id="AddNewDiv">

                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
        <partial name="_AddDependent" model="new DependentDto()" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
    </div>

    @section Scripts {
        @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
        <script>
            $(function () {
                $("#AddNewDependent").click(function (evt) {
                    debugger;
                    var data = new FormData();
                    data.append('id', $('#ItemCount').val());
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "/Home/AddNewDependents",
                        contentType: false,
                        processData: false,
                        data: data,
                        success: function (message) {
                            $('#AddNewDiv').html(message);
                            RemoveDependent();// call the remove function: attach the remove button click event.
                        },
                        error: function () {
                            alert("there was error !");
                        }
                    });
                });

                $("#AddDependent").click(function (evt) {
                    //create object, and get the new dependent value,
                    var dependent = {};
                    dependent.Id = $('#Id').val();
                    dependent.DependentName = $('#DependentName').val();
                    dependent.RelationToApplicant = $('#RelationToApplicant').val();
                    dependent.DependentDateOfBirth = $('#DependentDateOfBirth').val();

                    //call the AddDependents method and insert the new dependent.
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "/Home/AddDependents",
                        data: { "dependent": dependent },
                        success: function (message) {
                            $('#AddNewDiv').html(message);
                            RemoveDependent();
                        },
                        error: function () {
                            alert("there was error !");
                        }
                    });
                });

                function RemoveDependent() {
                    $(".DeleteDependent").each(function (index, item) {
                        $(item).click(function () {
                            var data = new FormData();
                            var id = $(this).attr("data-ItemId");
                            data.append('id', id);
                            $.ajax({
                                type: "POST",
                                url: "/Home/RemoveNewDependent",
                                contentType: false,
                                processData: false,
                                data: data,
                                success: function (message) {
                                    $('#AddNewDiv').html(message);
                                    RemoveDependent();
                                },
                                error: function () {
                                    alert("there was error !");
                                }
                            });
                        });
                    });
                }
            })
        </script>
    }
   ```
6. Controller:

   ```
    public const string SessionkeyMCD = "DependentDto";
    public IActionResult DependentIndex()
    {
        var newMedicalCardDto = new NewMedicalCardDto();
        if (HttpContext.Session.Get<NewMedicalCardDto>(SessionkeyMCD) == default)
        { 
            //store the model in the session
            HttpContext.Session.Set<NewMedicalCardDto>(SessionkeyMCD, newMedicalCardDto);
        }
        return View(newMedicalCardDto);
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult AddNewDependents(int id)
    {
        List<DependentDto> deplist = new List<DependentDto>();
        for (int i = 0; i < id + 1; i++)
        {
            deplist.Add(new DependentDto { Id = i, DependentName = "", RelationToApplicant = 0, DependentDateOfBirth = DateTime.Now, DependentNationalId = "", DependentMobileNumber = "" });
        }
        var newMedicalCardDto = new NewMedicalCardDto();
        newMedicalCardDto.DependentsDto = deplist;

        //each time click the AddNewDependent button, we will reset the session.   if you want to get the previous data, you could check if session is null and then get value from session, then, insert new data and update the session.
        //use session to store the Model data.
        HttpContext.Session.Set<NewMedicalCardDto>(SessionkeyMCD, newMedicalCardDto); 

        return PartialView("_Dependent", newMedicalCardDto);

    }
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult AddDependents(DependentDto dependent)
    { 
        var newMedicalCardDto = new NewMedicalCardDto();
        if (HttpContext.Session.Get<NewMedicalCardDto>(SessionkeyMCD) != default)
        {
            newMedicalCardDto = HttpContext.Session.Get<NewMedicalCardDto>(SessionkeyMCD);

            newMedicalCardDto.DependentsDto.Add(dependent);

            //use session to store the Model data.
            HttpContext.Session.Set<NewMedicalCardDto>(SessionkeyMCD, newMedicalCardDto);
        } 
        return PartialView("_Dependent", newMedicalCardDto);

    }
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult RemoveNewDependent(int id)
    {
        var newMedicalCardDto = new NewMedicalCardDto();
        if (HttpContext.Session.Get<NewMedicalCardDto>(SessionkeyMCD) != default)
        {
            //get the data from the session
            newMedicalCardDto = HttpContext.Session.Get<NewMedicalCardDto>(SessionkeyMCD);
            //remove item
            var remove = newMedicalCardDto.DependentsDto.Find(x => x.Id == id);
            newMedicalCardDto.DependentsDto.Remove(remove);
            //update the session data
            HttpContext.Session.Set<NewMedicalCardDto>(SessionkeyMCD, newMedicalCardDto);
        }

        return PartialView("_Dependent", newMedicalCardDto);
    }
   ```

The result as below: Once we click the AddNewDependent button, it will reset the session.

[image]

Comment: thank you for your time and the help , how can i do this without the DependentIndex page and keep it in the input value?

Comment: Hi @Abdulmajeed, Since the `_Dependent` is the partial view, there should have a main page to render the partial view, the dependentIndex page is the main page. So, the main page is required.

Comment: in <partial name="_AddDependent" model="new DependentDto()" /> i got an error the type or namespace name 'DependentDto' could not be found , i try to change it to  @{
                                        await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_AddDependent", Model.DependentsDto);
                                    }   but this is also give me an error because i'm sending generic list to the partial view , should i change the partial view to list also or u have better soluation for me