# how to add list of items from partial view using jquery to show in the browser with generated id to delete item by id

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

i'm trying to create a form that has a partial view allow the user to enter a list of dependent and show it to the user using other partial with delete button to every dependet
i try to use Zhi Lv soluation
[asp.net core mvc when add or remove partial view from controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68282146/asp-net-core-mvc-when-add-or-remove-partial-view-from-controller)

now i have 3 problem with this soluation

1- the id when i send the request from jquery will be always zero (i don't want the user to enter the id so i keep the id hidden) .
2- i have in the partial view an input to upload pdf file and the value is null .
3- after i try to submit the form when i check the request in the controller the informaion from the partial view isn't showing (the main model as parameter (NewMedicalCardDto)) .

here is my main view

```
@model PshrcPortal.Dto.NewMedicalCardDto
@{ Layout = "_NewLayout";
    ViewData["Title"] = "Details";
}
                <form class="form-signin" id="Dependentform" asp-controller="AddDependent" asp-action="SaveNewDependent" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                   <div class='row'>
 <div class="col-lg-6">
                                <div class="form-group required  mb-5">
                                    <label for="inputDate">DOB</label>
                                    <input required="" asp-for="ApplicantDOB" class="form-control addDependentInput" type="date" />
                                   
                                </div>
                            </div>
  <div class="col-sm-12 ">

                                <div  id="AddNewDiv1" class="container">
                                    <partial name="_AddDependent" model="new PshrcPortal.Dto.DependentDto()" />

                                    @*@{
                                        await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_dependent", );
                                    }*@

                                </div>
                                <div id="AddNewDiv">

                                </div>

                   </div>
```

the partial view to add the dependent

```
 <div class="row">
         <div class="form-group col-4">
             <label asp-for="Id" class="control-label"></label>
             <input asp-for="Id" class="form-control" />
         </div>
         <div class="form-group col-4">
             <label asp-for="DependentName" class="control-label"></label>
             <input asp-for="DependentName" class="form-control" />
         </div>
         <div class="form-group col-4">
             <label asp-for="RelationToApplicant" class="control-label"></label>
             <input asp-for="RelationToApplicant" class="form-control" />
         </div>
         <div class="form-group col-4">
             <label asp-for="DependentDateOfBirth" class="control-label"></label>
             <input asp-for="DependentDateOfBirth" class="form-control" />
         </div>
         <div class="form-group col-4">
             <label asp-for="DependentNationalId" class="control-label"></label>
              <input type="file"  data-buttonText="Find file" id="DependentNationalId" asp-for="DependentNationalId" required="">
         </div>
         <div class="form-group col-4">
             <label asp-for="DependentMobileNumber" class="control-label"></label>
             <input asp-for="DependentMobileNumber" class="form-control" />
         </div>
     </div>
     <div class="row"> 
         <div class="form-group">
             <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="AddDependent" value="AddDependent" />
         </div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

the jquery code to add dependent to other partial view

```
        $("#AddDependent").click(function (evt) {
            //create object, and get the new dependent value,
            var dependent = {};
            dependent.Id = $('#Id').val();
            dependent.DependentName = $('#DependentName').val();
            dependent.DependentDateOfBirth = $('#DependentDateOfBirth').val();
            dependent.DependentNationalId = $('#DependentNationalId').val();
            dependent.DependentMobileNumber = $('#DependentMobileNumber').val();


            //call the AddDependents method and insert the new dependent.
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/AddDependent/AddDependents",
                data: { "dependent": dependent },
                success: function (message) {
                    $('#AddNewDiv').html(message);
                    RemoveDependent();
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("there was error !");
                }
            });
        });
```

My model

```
 public class NewMedicalCardDto
    {
        public NewMedicalCardDto()
        {
            DependentsDto = new List<DependentDto>();
        }
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int ApplicantStatus { get; set; }
        public List<DependentDto> DependentsDto { get; set;}

}

public class DependentDto
 {
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string DependentName { get; set; }
}
```

this is my controller

```
public IActionResult AddNewDependent()
    {

        NewMedicalCardDto newMedicalCardDto = new NewMedicalCardDto();
        
        if (TempData["existRequestmsg"] != null)
        {
            ViewBag.Message = TempData["existRequestmsg"].ToString();
            TempData.Remove("existRequestmsg");
        }
        
        if (HttpContext.Session.Get<NewMedicalCardDto>(SessionkeyMCD) == default)
        {
            //store the model in the session
            HttpContext.Session.Set<NewMedicalCardDto>(SessionkeyMCD, newMedicalCardDto);
        }
        newMedicalCardDto.DependentsDto.Add(new DependentDto { Id = 1, DependentName = "", RelationToApplicant = 0, DependentDateOfBirth = DateTime.Now, DependentNationalId = "", DependentMobileNumber = "" });
        return View(newMedicalCardDto);
    }
    public IActionResult AddNewDependents(NewMedicalCardDto newMedicalCardDto, int id)
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < id + 1; i++)
        {
            newMedicalCardDto.DependentsDto.Add(new DependentDto { Id = i, DependentName = "", RelationToApplicant = 0, DependentDateOfBirth = DateTime.Now, DependentNationalId = "", DependentMobileNumber = "" });
        }
        return PartialView("_Dependent", newMedicalCardDto);

    }
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult AddDependents(DependentDto dependent)
    {
        var newMedicalCardDto = new NewMedicalCardDto();
        if (HttpContext.Session.Get<NewMedicalCardDto>(SessionkeyMCD) != default)
        {
            newMedicalCardDto = HttpContext.Session.Get<NewMedicalCardDto>(SessionkeyMCD);

            newMedicalCardDto.DependentsDto.Add(dependent);

            //use session to store the Model data.
            HttpContext.Session.Set(SessionkeyMCD, newMedicalCardDto);
        }
        return PartialView("_ShowDependent", newMedicalCardDto);
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult RemoveNewDependent(int id)
    {
        var newMedicalCardDto = new NewMedicalCardDto();
        if (HttpContext.Session.Get<NewMedicalCardDto>(SessionkeyMCD) != default)
        {
            //get the data from the session
            newMedicalCardDto = HttpContext.Session.Get<NewMedicalCardDto>(SessionkeyMCD);
            //remove item
            var remove = newMedicalCardDto.DependentsDto.Find(x => x.Id == id);
            newMedicalCardDto.DependentsDto.Remove(remove);
            //update the session data
            HttpContext.Session.Set<NewMedicalCardDto>(SessionkeyMCD, newMedicalCardDto);
        }

        return PartialView("_ShowDependent", newMedicalCardDto);
    }
    public IActionResult SaveNewDependent(NewMedicalCardDto newMedicalCardDto)
    { save the request here}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Hi @Abdulmajeed, `the id when i send the request from jquery will be always zero` which model's Id do you want to post?  `i have in the partial view an input to upload pdf file and the value is null .` If you want to post file, you need post by using formdata in ajax.`after i try to submit the form when i check the request in the controller the informaion from the partial view isn't showing (the main model as parameter (NewMedicalCardDto))` You only share the ajax about how to add the dependent, how do you post `NewMedicalCardDto`? Also, what is your backend code? Please share more code.

Comment: Hi @Rena ,1-  the id will be from dependentDto    2- do i have to change the way i declare the variable depndent in my jquery or i will just change (dependent.DependentNationalId = $('#DependentNationalId').val();)    3- i will edit my question to add the backend